# I have 163 raster files want to aggregate from 50 km to 100 km resolution using for loop. please guide me. thanks

Tags: r, r-raster

```
library(raster)
library(stringr)
setwd("file.choose")
tws50km =list.files(pattern=".tif",full.names = F)
time_list <- str_sub(gsub("-", "", seq(as.Date("2002/4/1"), by = "month", length.out = 163)), 1,6)

for (i in 1:length(tws50km)){
   tws100km = aggregate(i, fact = 2, fun = mean)
   writeRaster(tws100km,paste('tws_',time_list[i], ".tif", sep = " "), "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE) 
}
```

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: if you change `aggregate(i` to `aggregate(tws50km[i]` ?

Comment: still its not working.

Comment: I'd give Robert's answer a try as he wrote `raster`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this

```
library(raster)
inf <- list.files(pattern=".tif",full.names = F)
```

It is easiest to make all output filenames in step, as I show below. But what you are doing does not look good. How do you know that you are using the right filename, that they match the data? You would normally change the input filenames `inf` in some way. But I cannot improve your approach as you do not shown any input file names.

```
outf <- substr(gsub("-", "", seq(as.Date("2002/4/1"), by="month", length.out=163)), 1,6)
# use paste0, avoid spaces in filenames
outf <- paste0('tws_', outf, ".tif")
outf[1:2]
#[1] "tws_200204.tif" "tws_200205.tif"
```

Now loop. First create a RasterLayer with raster (or use `brick` if there multiple layers), then aggregate that object (you cannot aggregate a filename!). No need for `writeRaster` as aggregate has its own `filename` argument.

```
for (i in 1:length(inf)) {
    r <- raster(inf[i])
    x <- aggregate(r, fact=2, fun=mean, filename=outf[i], overwrite=TRUE) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date code is just fine and I wasn't thinking fully when I commented, but you need to progressively update everything as you go through your loop, so we'll put `[i]` everywhere that things are going from 1-2-3~163

```
library(raster)
library(stringr)
setwd("file.choose")
tws50km =list.files(pattern=".tif",full.names = F)
```

I did change `time_list` to `time_month` both here and in the loop because 
in the future you'll want to know that this is a character vector accessed by
`[`, and not a list accessed by `[[`

```
time_month <- str_sub(gsub("-", "", seq(as.Date("2002/4/1"), by = "month", length.out = 163)), 1,6)
```

So just copying your for loop and thinking `[i]`:

```
for (i in 1:length(tws50km)){
   tws100km[i] = aggregate(tws50km[i], fact = 2, fun = mean)
   writeRaster(tws100km[i],paste('tws_',time_month[i], ".tif", sep = " "), "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE) 
}
```

and hopefully this does it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it did not work. I already got one above answer which solved my problem.

Comment: @ShoaibAli You should accept Robert's answer above as it shows this question answered and helps future users.

Comment: Yes I accepted Robert's answer and said to thanks in the above comment.